# @push(custom-scripts') not working laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

In laravel I'm using scripts.In view,

```
@push('custom-scripts')
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 @endpush
```

This is not working,But when use pushonce method instead,

It's working,and the code like

```
@pushonce('custom-scripts')
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 @endpushonce
```

Why it's not working?
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make that the opposite way, @push is meant to be in the child view, which is pushing content to the parent @stash directive.
So your index.blade.php should have a:

```
@stack('custom-scripts')
```

And your Child View

```
@push('custom-scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset ('js/custom-scripts.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

Comment: No it's not working Here is code in child view `
@push('custom-scripts')
  <script src="{{ asset("js/jquery.nicescroll.js") }}"></script>
@endpush` And in Master blade ` @stack('custom-scripts') `